# Would the same equilibrium concentration of carbon dioxide, carbon monoxide and oxygen always result for a given initial atomic carbon fraction?

Tags: equilibrium, gas-phase-chemistry

**Question:** Starting with a gas mixture of some combination of gases containing carbon and oxygen with a total carbon atomic fraction $f$, would it always reach the same equilibrium proportions of $\ce{CO2 + O2 + CO}$?

For example if I had an equal number of $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{O2}$ molecules then $f=0.2$, but so would two molecules of $\ce{CO2}$ for every three molecules of $\ce{O2}$. If I started with either mixture in this example, would I end up with the same equilibrium mixture of $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{O2}$?

**Simplifying assumptions:** Assume $\pu{273K}$ and $\pu{610Pa}$ if necessary, the answer may be as simple as "yes it would" or "no it wouldn't, because...", a supply of ionizing radiation from space (hard UV and energetic cosmic ray particles) and a billion years, and ignore transmutation of elements by those particles.

---

Background and motivation is from my Space Exploration SE question [Are Mars' atmospheric CO₂, O₂ and CO in equilibrium? Are sunlight or chemical reactions involved?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41094/12102), which begins:

> According to the NASA JPL video linked below the top five gases comprising the martian atmosphere include $\ce{CO₂, O₂}$ and $\ce{CO}$. Do the proportions reflect some chemical equilibrium? Are sunlight or chemical reactions involved in maintaining these proportions?

```
Component     Fraction
   CO2          95.9%
   Ar            2.0%
   N2            1.9%
   O2            0.14%
   CO            0.06%
```

> The NASA JPL video **[Crazy Engineering: Making Oxygen on Mars with MOXIE](https://youtu.be/7rzu7TTkIMA)** is linked in [How many square meters of solar panel to power a MOXIE-like oxygen source per person?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41091/12102).

Comment: I'm guessing that the answer is "yes it would" but I'm not a chemist.

Comment: As soon as the mixture is allowed to reach equilibrium in the first place, yes. (I guess a billion years is quite enough.) Short of that, no.

Comment: Obviously not, because mars rotates and has a climate, with seasons. ;)

Comment: @SurArthur7 thanks for the edit! I've never seen `\pu{}` used before but it looks great. I didn't find it in [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/284619) so I'm wondering 1) what it's called, and 2) if it should be added there somewhere?

Comment: @Karl this question is not about Mars. That was included as "Background and motivation" but for this question in Chemistry SE I've stipulated a *constant temperature and pressure* for this gas mixture.

Comment: I would add that you should assume in addition that oxygen is present in the same atomic ratio to carbon. By the definition of an equilibrium constant you would expect the one equilibrium composition at constant T,P (nitrogen being assumed inertial). However if you are irradiating the system with high energy particles you might see substantial fluctuations (or perhaps steady-state but not true equilibrium). Something like what happens in our own ozone layer.

Comment: Interesting aside, Wikipedia says: "Venus also has a thin ozone layer at an altitude of 100 kilometers above the planet's surface.[5] " Venus' atmosphere is mostly CO2.

Comment: @BuckThorn I think Venus' atomosphere is going to turn out to be a really interesting case, much more complicated than Mars'. There are now three approved missions (NASA + ESA) and there will be detailed atmospheric studies... https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01634-3 and [ESA's](https://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Space_Science/ESA_selects_revolutionary_Venus_mission_EnVision?fbclid=IwAR3L9d3rC4BfuXAk5KpKQzdIUh80Q7VVzRi55dwDCLYRiTyCtm_3d6BGYYo) and [NASA's](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-selects-2-missions-to-study-lost-habitable-world-of-venus)